# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Windows

Tags: mysql

- ISSUE:

Unable to start/connect to the MySQL server that worked successfully early

- ENVIRONMENT:

Windows 10

- PRECONDITIONS:

From any reason my MySQL server stopped to run.
And I was started to receive error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)` after I was trying to connect with `mysql -uroot -pppp`

In the Service window I tried to start MySQL and received error:

```
The MySQL service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop Automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs
```

I had reinstalled (several times) MySQL and executed following command: `mysqld --initilize`
After that I can start my server.

**Now** I try to login to MySQL with command

`mysql -uroot -pppp` and now I receive the error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

- Steps:

`net stop mysql`
`mysqld --console --skip-grant-tables` mysql -uroot`

In the console I try to set password for the root user but every time receive error.

My attempts:

- `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password', authentication_string=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root';`

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("password") WHERE User="root"' at line 1

- `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'new_password'`;

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Please help.
I even agree to drop mysql fully from PC and reinstall again. But I am not sure - I reinstalled already and it not help.